# Does each core have its own private set of registers?

Tags: memory, memory-management, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture

Looking at this Intel core i7 nehalem micro-architecture
[image]

it seems that each core has its own private Register File. So I have a couple of short questions, because I thought that there is only 1 set of registers not dependent on the number of cores.

- Does each core have its own private set of registers? (RAX, RBX, RSP and so on).
- Does each core have its own MMU and TLB? Not just one shared across all cores?

I know the questions are highly micro-architecture dependent but I think the majority of modern x64 Intel cpu's follow the same design principle.

Comment: Note that the question appears off-topic here: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."

Comment: @njuffa well registers are related to programming so it is good to know more about them :)

Comment: While each has it's own registers, the ability to specify which core is set when loading rax, rbx, rsp and so on isn't generically supported.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each core has its own set of registers, MMU, TLB, level 1 caches (data and instruction), level 2 cache (this depends on processor) etc. Cache Coherency is supported across cores via "QPI" and in the case of high end Core 7 and server-based processors like Xeon, Cache Coherency is supported across processors on a multi-processor mother board by exposing "QPI" on the external pins of those processors (for processors where multi-processor cache coherency is not supported, "QPI" is not "exposed").

Wiki article: [Nehalem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nehalem_%28microarchitecture%29)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, each core has its set of registers. "Core" is equivalent of separate CPU on socket but with "multicore" the electronic wiring is simple.