# multi core processer and register sets for each core?

Tags: assembly, simd, avx512

[Does each core has its own private set of registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815848/does-each-core-has-its-own-private-set-of-registers)

The ref above states each core has its own set of registers. My question is how can you access core1's RAX and core2's RAX core3's RAX and core4's RAX in assembly mov ??? RAX. Is this a specific instruction set similar to AVX-512 instructions? Is there specific instruction sets for access to the other cores?

Use other cores register sets

Comment: You can't access another core's registers directly.  Communication between threads is via memory, so code on that other core (or thread) has to run instructions that store values in to memory where it's visible.  AVX-512 is not special in any way for this; `k0-7` and `zmm0-31` mask and vector registers are thread-private just like integer regs and mm0-7, ymm0-16.

Comment: Your process is running on just one core.  Other processes are running on the other cores.  Would you be happy if those other processes on other cores stole *your* registers?  No you would not be  :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am taking an assembly language class currently and I was wondering about this.